# SEO implications of having EN hreflang with German content

Tags: seo, hreflang

we're trying to understand whether there will be any serious SEO implications impacting the website in the following situation: We've got one URL (/events) with hreflang being en, however, it can also show an event in German language or Turkish and the URL still being /en/events. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2):

The W3C standard does have lang= support for individual elements.

IE:

```
<p lang="fr">Ceci est un paragraphe.</p>
```

If practical putting the German with-in a div with a Lang tag for German may help your English visitors in translating the German, and vis-versa for German to English.

Google is aware that pages exist where there is a use case for multiple languages on the same page. IE a page with side-by-side translation for one or more languages.

The use case you are describing would be German content within an otherwise English web page. Google would rather websites keep it simple and use one language on a page. A very old acknowledgment that pages exist in more than one language ...

> https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites Published in 2010.
> Google tries to determine the main languages of each one of your
> pages. You can help to make language recognition easier if you stick
> to only one language per page and avoid side-by-side translations.
> Although Google can recognize a page as being in more than one
> language, we recommend using the same language for all elements of a
> page: headers, sidebars, menus, etc.

As for SEO impact, it would not receive a penalty nor be considered as bad content because it has multiple languages. But it also won't receive any improvement for SEO. It may be difficult to rank for terms when two languages are used ... synonyms for example re-enforce terms on a page/site but other languages are not synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get traffic on the existing /events page? If you do, changing its content based on language might confuse search engines. Additional question: do you expect to rank for German or Turkish queries? The best way to ensure this happens is to have dedicated (static) pages for the new locals. /de/events or /tr/events with the hreflang correctly implemented.